# Compute not updating if radio is checked through code

Tags: vue.js

Sorry for the title, didn't know how I could better explain it.

I have 3 radio buttons. The output should be the value of whichever radio button is selected. Except, the 3rd radio button has a textarea, and if that radio button is selected, the resulting output should be what is in the textarea. I've also linked the `@click` of textarea to automatically check the radio button, so if a user clicks on the textarea, that radio button gets checked automatically.

Everything works, if you see the JSFiddle code and click on the 3rd radio button and type text in the textarea, the output should work fine. But if you refresh the page, and instead of clicking the radio button, if you directly click on the textarea (which indirectly checks the radio button), writing in the textarea will not update the output. Which means the compute function is not working.

However if you click on another radio button and then click back on the 3rd radio button, things will start working fine.

Here's the code (JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/43651/ )

```
<div id="app">
    Selected option 1: {{ selectedText }}
  <BR>

  <input type="radio" name="item1" value="" v-model="selected[0]" /> Empty<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="item1" value="Hi" v-model="selected[0]" /> Hi<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="item1" value="**custom**" v-model="selected[0]" /> <textarea name="textarea0" id="textarea0" cols="30" rows="10" v-model="custom[0]" @click="customClicked"></textarea><BR>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        selected: ['', ''],
    custom: ['', ''],
  },

  computed: {
    selectedText: function() {
        if (this.selected[0] != '**custom**') return this.selected[0];

      return this.custom[0];
    }
  },

  methods: {
    customClicked: function(e) {
        //$(e.target).prev().prop('checked', true);
      this.selected[0] = '**custom**';
      this.$forceUpdate();
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this - just bind the values to one array and use `@focus` event on the `textarea`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    values: ['', 'Hi', ''],
    selected: '',
  },
  computed: {
    selectedText: function() {
      return this.values[this.selected];
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">

  Selected option 1: {{ selectedText }}
  <BR/>

  <input type="radio" name="item1" value="0" v-model="selected" /> Empty
  <BR/>
  <input type="radio" name="item1" value="1" v-model="selected" /> Hi
  <BR />
  <input type="radio" name="item1" value="2" v-model="selected" />

  <textarea name="textarea0" id="textarea0" cols="30" rows="10" v-model="values[2]" @focus="selected = '2'"></textarea>

</div>
```

[Also the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/43737/).

Answer (score 1):

### Update

As the questioner choose another answer, but i don't think that is the key point.

The reason is `$forceUpdate()` only force the view to re-render, not the computed properties. See the issue [forceUpdate does not update computed fields](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7395)

And i create a simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/43894/) to descript it.

---

### Raw Answer

The problem you faced is that vuejs cannot detect array change in some situation. You can see more detail in the doc [vuejs list rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

So the solution is replaced these code

```
this.selected[0] = '**custom**';
this.$forceUpdate();
```

with

```
this.$set(this.selected, 0, '**custom**')
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. Similarly I also found that using ".click()" fixed my issue (see my own answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49872173/296540). However I chose that answer as Best because I was looking for a better way to solve this problem.
Still, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While writing the answer I got an idea and it seems to work. However I still want to know if there is a "right" way of doing things which I'm missing.

The fix was to "click" the radio button instead of "checking" it:

```
$(e.target).prev().click();
```